# Ok, to have a gas stove near a window?

Tags: appliances, gas, stove

Usually stoves are positioned against a wall. Is there any reason why I can't have a stove near a window in the center of the room?

[image: kitchen layout]

The stove is currently in the position on the left, against the wall, next to the sink. The proposed position is on the right. There will be an island on the left of the new stove too, which is not shown.

The reason for the change is to get more countertop next to the sink. Also, it will be easier to vent the stove outside (the current cooktop is not vented). Also, the gas run will be shorter (the current stove is electric).

Comment: It's still against a wall, right? What's your concern?

Comment: I don't know, I just don't see many stoves in the middle of a kitchen, so I thought there might be some reason. One issue is that the back of the stove is not against a wall. Not sure if that is important or not.

Comment: You haven't made it clear why it's not against the wall between the windows, or how far from the wall it'll be. "In the middle of the kitchen" isn't accurate.

Comment: Read the installation manual.  Window vs. nonwindow doesn't matter, but there are important spacing requirements on the rear and the sides, and depending on the stove (and you locale), possible requirements for heat shields on the back wall or side cabinets (if any)